# Coordinate system with text in each quadrant

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, coordinates

I am trying to reproduce this diagram

[image]

So far I have tried

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    node distance=1.5cm,
    filled/.style={circle,fill=red,text=white,minimum size=2cm}
]
\node [filled,label=below:{Primary Optical Area}] (1) {1};
\node [right=2cm of 1,filled,label=below:{Strong Fallow Area}] (2) {2};
\node [below=2cm of 1,filled,label=below:{Weak Fallow Area}] (3) {3};
\node [right=2cm of 3,filled,label=below:{Terminal Area}] (4) {4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

which is not quite what I want.

How do I make the coordinate system, so it is equivalent with the first picture?

Comment: Do you need the fading of the lines?

Comment: No, it is fine without the fading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple options here. Positioning the lines becomes easier if you place all the nodes relative to (0,0), then you can just do as below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    node distance=1.4cm and 2.2cm,
    filled/.style={circle,fill=red,text=white,minimum size=2cm,font=\Huge},
    label distance=5pt
]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\node [above left=of O,filled,label=below:{Primary Optical Area}] (1) {1};
\node [above right=of O,filled,label=below:{Strong Fallow Area}] (2) {2};
\node [below left=of O,filled,label=below:{Weak Fallow Area}] (3) {3};
\node [below right=of O,filled,label=below:{Terminal Area}] (4) {4};

\draw (0,4) -- (0,-4);
\draw (4,0) -- (-4,0);
\draw [dashed,-latex,red] (1) -- (2);
\draw [dashed,-latex,red] (2) -- (3);
\draw [dashed,-latex,red] (3) -- (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! But what about increasing the font size of the number within the circles and adding a small distance between the label and the circle?

Comment: @Jamgreen `font=\Huge` added to the `filled` style, and `label distance=5pt` (or some other length) added to the `tikzpicture` options, see edited code.

Comment: Even though it is not needed, the fading is not too difficult to achieve:`\fill[left color=white,right color=black] (-4.5,-.2pt) rectangle (0,.2pt);
 \fill[left color=black,right color=white] (0,-.2pt) rectangle (4.5,.2pt);
 \fill[top color=white,bottom color=black] (-.2pt,4.5) rectangle (.2pt,0);
 \fill[top color=black,bottom color=white] (-.2pt,0) rectangle (.2pt,-4.5);` instead of the line drawings.

Comment: @Jamgreen FYI, see nox' comment above.