# Create a four-fielder

Tags: graphics

I would like to create a four-fielder looking like this in LaTeX. Any ideas? [image]

Comment: A modification could be made of this [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346648/coordinate-system-with-text-in-each-quadrant)  or this [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309425/how-is-it-possible-to-make-a-magic-quadrant).

Comment: Welcome. // You should be able to do it after skimming through the tutorial(s) at tikz.dev ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procrastination mode on...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,every node/.style={align=left}]]
\sffamily
\draw[thick,<->](-4,0)node[above right,font=\scriptsize]{Stor\\arbetsintas}--(4,0)node[above left,font=\scriptsize]{Låg\\arbetsintas};
\draw[thick,<->](0,-2.5)node[below,font=\scriptsize]{Liten effekt}--(0,2.5)node[above,font=\scriptsize]{Stor effekt};
\node[left,font=\bfseries] at (-.5,1.5){Tar lång tid att\\skapa, men ger\\stor effekt};
\node[right,font=\bfseries] at (.5,1.5){Går fort att skapa\\och ger stor effekt};
\node[left,font=\bfseries] at (-.5,-1.5){Tar lång tid att\\skapa, men ger\\liten effekt};
\node[right,font=\bfseries] at (.5,-1.5){Går fort att skapa\\och ger liten effekt};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]